# TAM to ISAM migration for SOAP services

Tags: soap, websphere, saml, ws-security, isam

We are currently using IBM TAM infrastructure for authorization of user for front end application. Our front end application then call another common application via SOAP and generate and propagate LTPA security token where common application consumes LTPA token and perform operation. We have IBM binding files which create web services binding defined in template. These binding file names are ibm-webservicesclient-bnd.xmi and ibm-webservicesclient-ext.xmi. Now I want to remove LTPA related classes from these bindings files and add SAML token related classes. Do we really need these files in case of SAML and ISAM? We are using IBM WebSphere as an application server. If these files are required then which classes I should use in bindings .xmi files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using JAX-RPC, not JAX-WS. WebSphere JAX-RPC does not SAML propagation. WebSphere JAX-WS supports SAML propagation  as defined in https://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-SAMLTokenProfile.pdf. Here is the link to examples, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972078.